# RestKit test mapping with RKObjectMapping in separate class not working

Tags: ios, mapping, restkit, xctest

I have a Model-class `ApplicationError` which looks like this:

```
@interface ApplicationError : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *status;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *code;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *message;
@end
```

In a separate class `MappingProvider`, I create my `RKObjectMapping` to fit this model:

```
@implementation MappingProvider

+ (RKObjectMapping *)mappingForApplicationError {
    RKObjectMapping *errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ApplicationError class]];
    [errorMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:[self propertiesError]];
    return errorMapping;
}

+ (NSArray *)propertiesError {
    return @[@"status", @"code", @"message"];
}
```

When testing this mapping, my test does not succeed like it should.

```
- (void)testMappingOfStatus {

    RKObjectMapping *errorMapping = [MappingProvider mappingForApplicationError];
    RKMappingTest *mappingTest = [RKMappingTest testForMapping:errorMapping sourceObject:self.parsedJSON destinationObject:nil];
    [mappingTest addExpectation:[RKPropertyMappingTestExpectation expectationWithSourceKeyPath:@"status" destinationKeyPath:@"status"]];
    XCTAssert([mappingTest evaluate]);
}
```

`self.parsedJSON` is an `id`-object parsed from a Fixture-JSON-file.
When I create my errorMapping in this method (instead of in the separate `MappingProvider`-class, everything works fine.

```
RKObjectMapping *errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ApplicationError class]];
[errorMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"status", @"code", @"message"]];
```

When logging both versions, they look the same (only the memory-location is different).
Any ideas why this is happening?

UPDATE

Logging shows:

```
AE_MAPPING_1 = <RKObjectMapping:0x1501a750 objectClass=ApplicationError propertyMappings=(
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1505e0b0 status => status>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1505e0c0 code => code>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x15a94850 message => message>"
)>

AE_MAPPING_2 = <RKObjectMapping:0x1505a660 objectClass=ApplicationError propertyMappings=(
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1505b620 status => status>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1505b630 code => code>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1505b640 message => message>"
)>

(([mappingTest evaluate]) is true) failed: throwing "0x15a98f60: failed with error: (null)
RKMappingTest Expectations: (
    "map 'status' to 'status'"
)
Events: (
) during mapping from <CFBasicHash 0x15031030 [0x31d8ec8]>{type = immutable dict, count = 3,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x15a957b0 [0x31d8ec8]>{contents = "status"} = <CFNumber 0x15a95240 [0x31d8ec8]>{value = +400, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
    1 : <CFString 0x15a95250 [0x31d8ec8]>{contents = "code"} = <CFNumber 0x15a95c00 [0x31d8ec8]>{value = +4002, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
    2 : <CFString 0x15a96130 [0x31d8ec8]>{contents = "message"} = <CFString 0x15a97310 [0x31d8ec8]>{contents = "Something went wrong."}
}
to (null) with mapping <RKObjectMapping:0x1505a660 objectClass=ApplicationError propertyMappings=(
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1505b620 status => status>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1505b630 code => code>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1505b640 message => message>"
)>"

error: -[ApplicationErrorMappingTests testMappingOfStatus] : (([mappingTest evaluate]) is true) failed: throwing "0x15a98f60: failed with error: (null)
RKMappingTest Expectations: (
    "map 'status' to 'status'"
)
Events: (
) during mapping from <CFBasicHash 0x15031030 [0x31d8ec8]>{type = immutable dict, count = 3,
entries =>
    0 : <CFString 0x15a957b0 [0x31d8ec8]>{contents = "status"} = <CFNumber 0x15a95240 [0x31d8ec8]>{value = +400, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
    1 : <CFString 0x15a95250 [0x31d8ec8]>{contents = "code"} = <CFNumber 0x15a95c00 [0x31d8ec8]>{value = +4002, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
    2 : <CFString 0x15a96130 [0x31d8ec8]>{contents = "message"} = <CFString 0x15a97310 [0x31d8ec8]>{contents = "Something went wrong."}
}
 to (null) with mapping <RKObjectMapping:0x1505a660 objectClass=ApplicationError propertyMappings=(
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1505b620 status => status>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1505b630 code => code>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x1505b640 message => message>"
)>"
```

Comment: And the JSON is the same in both tests? What is the JSON? The code looks ok.

Comment: json looks like this: 
    {
        "status": 400,
        "code": 4002,
        "message": "Something went wrong."
    }

Comment: it's strange that it is working for the second option (with the mapping declared inside the test-method), but I would rather not copy/paste my provider-class and just use it...

Comment: The code posted looks ok, in both cases. If the JSON in one test is an array of dictionaries then it should fail. Other than that no problem is evident... Trace logging may help

Comment: question is updated with logging statements ;-)

Comment: What version of RestKit are you using?

Comment: my Podfile says Restkit ~> 0.20.3 (also for Restkit/Testing 0.20.3)

Comment: Update to 0.23.1 (or at least 0.22.0)

Comment: Update to 0.23.1 didn't fix it.
What fixed it: apparently, you have to add the separate class (in my case the `MappingProvider`-class) in your test-target.
It is not enough to add the class to your linked dev-target...

Comment: Well, glad you have a solution, even if I would expect the app to have crashed rather than the test to fail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: apparently, you have to add the separate class (in my case the `MappingProvider`-class) in your test-target.

It is not enough to add the class to your linked dev-target...